# SVM - Why we use the dual theorem?

Tags: svm, optimization

Why in SVM we use the **dual theorem**? I can't understand why we cannot minimize the norm of the weights **w** directly.

Answer (score 1):

A **quick answer**: is that solving **the dual problem** is, in many practical cases, **easier to solve** (more tractable algorithms exist), than the primal problem and **leads to the solution of the primal problem as well**.

Exception to this, is Linear SVMs, where the primal problem is equally easy.

**Note**: The primal/dual is a general method that can be used in many areas of optimization, SVMs are simply one such application of this method.

Reference:

[Support Vector Machines for Beginners – Duality Problem](http://www.adeveloperdiary.com/data-science/machine-learning/support-vector-machines-for-beginners-duality-problem/)